# Scheduling a custom report to be sent as a CSV file in an email

Tags: email, reporting, csv

Is it possible to send a custom report out as a CSV file using APEX email templates?

If so does anyone have the steps to do so?
I am new to Salesforce and would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.